# cv.cornerSubPix parameters in the OpenCV Python Library

Tags: python, opencv, calibration, subpixel

I am having problems getting the following function to execute using the OpenCV python wrapper:

```
img = cv.LoadImage("calib0.jpg")
grayImg = cv.CreateImage((img.width,img.height), img.depth,1)
cv.CvtColor(img,grayImg,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
corners = cv.FindChessboardCorners(grayImg,(5,6), cv.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + cv.CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE + cv.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK )
cv.cornerSubPix(grayImg,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 0.01))
```

If I run this in iPython on (OSX) I get the following error:

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/katherinescott/simplecv-git/SimpleCV/sampleimages/ in ()
----> 1 cv.cornerSubPix(grayImg,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 0.01))

TypeError:  is not a numpy array

I've tried just about every permutation of casting the above objects to a numpy ndarray but to no avail. My guess is that this error lives in the term criteria object, but I am at a loss as to what it is asking for. Has anyone else encountered this problem when trying to perform calibration using the OpenCV Python wrappers? I am about to start digging into the source to see what I can find.

Comment: UPDATE: with later versions of opencv (>=2.7) there is some changes in grammar- this worked for me when I changed the criteria to : criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cornerSubPix, having a lowercase letter first, is a module-internal function for the OpenCV python wrapper.

I believe you want cv.FindCornerSubPix:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_feature_detection.html#findcornersubpix

Comment: It works! The correct call is: cv.FindCornerSubPix(grayImg,corners[1],(11,11),(-1,-1),(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10, 0.01))

Comment: Functions starting with lowercase are from the C++ or cv2 Python library, what is the "this should be used" version of it. cv is there mostly for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I believe there may be some misunderstanding with the `winSize` parameter in `cv.cornerSubPix()`.

When using

```
cv.cornerSubPix(grayImg, corners, winSize, (-1,-1), criteria)
```

Assuming you want an 11x11 search window, the appropriate input for `winSize` should be `winSize=(5,5)` and not `winSize=(11,11)`. If you use (11,11) for `winSize` as posted in the original question, the resulting search window would actually be 23x23.

According to the documentation:

> winSize: Half of the side length of the search window. For example, if winSize=Size(5,5) , then a (5∗2+1)×(5∗2+1)=11×11 search window is used.

As of OpenCV 4.5.2 (April 2021), the example in the documentation under related `cv.findChessboardCorners()` appears to be incorrect and (5,5) for winSize should be used instead.

Comment: this was a nearly ten year old question for an OpenCV that is three versions out of date.